# Автоматическое определение языка и маппинг JSP данными

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Имеется такая задача.
Есть страница JSP, она должна формироваться на основании языка пользователя.
С определением языка вопрос решен. Некий массив со значениями вариантов слов создан.
Каким образом передать массу значений за минимальное количество действий с класса с массивом в сервлет, расставить все на свои места и только потом показать пользователю ?
Для каждого значения писать request.setAttribute("var", value) долго, утомительно и, наверное, не оправданно глупо.
Как правильно реализовать ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ используя проперти файлы.
На самой jsp подключаются jstl:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

по ключу в зависимости от локали вынимается сообщение:

```
<spring:message code="label.message.expired" />
```

Подробнее:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html

Comment: создал файлы проперти. Определяю локаль и выбираю нужный файл с значениями ключ=параметр. `ResourceBundle` передаю через `session.setAttribute`. Каким образом вытащить в JSP, чтобы достучаться по ключу ? Желательно без spring'a

Comment: может быть поступить проще и передавать через сессию не всё вместе, а только путь к файлу локализации ? С другой стороны, в примере в документации передают через сессию полностью все пары ключ=значение.

Comment: Можно java.util.ResourseBundle создавать на jsp, и в скриплетах вынимать